# Excel Write to get multiple data frames on the same sheet with multiple sheets and formatting the data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

[What each sheet needs to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlx0n.png)I am trying to write 6 data frames to one excel sheet and then write 6 different data frames to another excel sheet in the same workbook. I know the code below is not that great, but it works to get the data frames into the same sheet and spaced out.

I am also trying to format the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns for all data frames to be a number with commas (1,000), dollars ($1,000.00) and percentages (50.12%) respectively
I could really use anyone's help with this. Thank you in advance

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\SS012420\Desktop\LoanPool_07082021_.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pooled_Loans')
    summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
    GEO8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8')
    OTM8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8', startcol = (2 + len(GEO8.columns)), startrow = 0)
    RTM8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8', startcol = (2+ len(GEO8.columns) + 2 + len(OTM8.columns)), startrow = 0)
    FICO8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8', startcol = (2+len(GEO8.columns) + 2 + len(OTM8.columns) +2 + len(RTM8.columns)), startrow = 0)
    APR8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8', startcol = (2+len(GEO8.columns) + 2 + len(OTM8.columns) +2 + len(RTM8.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO8.columns)), startrow = 0)
    PB8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table8', startcol = (2+len(GEO8.columns) + 2 + len(OTM8.columns) +2 + len(RTM8.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO8.columns) + 2 + len(APR8.columns)), startrow = 0)
    GEO12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12')
    OTM12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12', startcol = (2 + len(GEO12.columns)), startrow = 0)
    RTM12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12', startcol = (2+ len(GEO12.columns) + 2 + len(OTM12.columns)), startrow = 0)
    FICO12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12', startcol = (2+len(GEO12.columns) + 2 + len(OTM12.columns) +2 + len(RTM12.columns)), startrow = 0)
    APR12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12', startcol = (2+len(GEO12.columns) + 2 + len(OTM12.columns) +2 + len(RTM12.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO12.columns)), startrow = 0)
    PB12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table12', startcol = (2+len(GEO12.columns) + 2 + len(OTM12.columns) +2 + len(RTM12.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO12.columns) + 2 + len(APR12.columns)), startrow = 0) 
    GEO19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19')
    OTM19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19', startcol = (2 + len(GEO19.columns)), startrow = 0)
    RTM19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19', startcol = (2+ len(GEO19.columns) + 2 + len(OTM19.columns)), startrow = 0)
    FICO19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19', startcol = (2+len(GEO19.columns) + 2 + len(OTM19.columns) +2 + len(RTM19.columns)), startrow = 0)
    APR19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19', startcol = (2+len(GEO19.columns) + 2 + len(OTM19.columns) +2 + len(RTM19.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO19.columns)), startrow = 0)
    PB19.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Strat_Table19', startcol = (2+len(GEO19.columns) + 2 + len(OTM19.columns) +2 + len(RTM19.columns)+ 2 + len(FICO19.columns) + 2 + len(APR19.columns)), startrow = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given dataframe try as an example...

```
#add $ (dollar) and commas to column
df['aNumberSeries'] = df.apply(lambda x: "${:,}".format(x['aNumberSeries']), axis=1)

#add % to a column of floats
df['aFloatSeries'] = df['aFloatSeries'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
```

**Example input:**

```
    aNumberSeries     aFloatSeries
0   1404338840        0.5670
1   1366938189        0.2345
2   330267887         0.5000
3   269603400         0.4220
```

**Example output:**

```
    aNumberSeries     aFloatSeries
0   $1,404,338,840.0  56.70%
1   $1,366,938,189.0  23.45%
2   $330,267,887.0    50.00%
3   $269,603,400.0    42.20%
```